# From Procedure to View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Code below works perfect as procedure.
How can I transform or change the same code below so that it can work in View or as View code or View?

Can I drop View?

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[NewOne_1]
as
begin
set nocount on

if  object_ID('TEMPDB..#TableA') <> ''
drop table # TableA
select 
    *
into # TableA
from vd_View  po   

if object_ID('TEMPDB..#FirstSDate') is not null  
   drop table #FirstSDate
select 
    Pt_id = Pat_Id,
    Date_of_First_Shipment = min(DeliveryDate)
into #FSDate    
from # TableA  po
group by Pat_Id        

if object_ID('TEMPDB..#LastSDate') is not null   
   drop table #LastShipDate
select 
    Pt_id = Pat_Id,
    Date_of_Last_Shipment = max(DeliveryDate)
into #LastShipDate  
from # TableA  po
group by Pat_Id                                  

SELECT PtData.Pat_No                Progress_Pat_ID
    ,C_S = case when  dbo.fn_GetBusinessDays(firstship.Date_of_First_Shipment,LastShip.Date_of_Last_Shipment) > 80 then 'Yes'  
                                         when  dbo.fn_GetBusinessDays(firstship.Date_of_First_Shipment,LastShip.Date_of_Last_Shipment) <= 80 then 'No' 
                                        else ''
                                        end
    ,P_Last_Name = PtData.P_LName
    ,PtData.DReg        Reg
    FROM dbo.tbld_PatSum PtData
    inner join vd_PSum ps
        on PtData.P = ps.P_ID
    inner join S_M.dbo.Pat__c ps1 
        on PtData.Pt_ID = ps1.Id              
        left join #FirstShipDate firstship    
        on PtData.Pt_ID = firstship.Pt_Id     
        left join #LastShipDate LastShip      
        on PtData.Pt_ID = LastShip.Pt_Id      
        WHERE PtData.Pat_No IS NOT NULL 
        AND PtData.ActiveStatus<>'Gen Info'

    set nocount off
end
```

Comment: You can't put that code into a view as explained yesterday. Views cannot contain procedural logic or do things like dropping tables.

Comment: How can I trasform this code so that it works on View. As requested I put the code now. I have to do that for C_S column

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What does `How can I transform or change the same code below so that it can work in View or as View code or View? ` mean? You have to do what for the `C_S column`?

Comment: I want to add the same logic in View script. Right click on View and then script view as and then alter to and you will see the code assosiated with that View. I like to add the code above in the View code.

Comment: OK. Well the answer to that is easy then. You can't. Views must be a single select statement and can not have this type of code.

Comment: This guy seems to think that if asks how to do it enough times that somehow SQL will magically grow that capability.

Comment: Yes, I do want to know if there is a way.......if not then not......

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're wanting to be able to use this to join with something else. You cannot put this into a view. However you may be able to put this in a table-valued function which would allow you to accomplish what I think you're after.

Comment: table valued functions can't do things like drop and create temporary tables either.

Comment: Can we use If Object_ID (View) and drop View?

Comment: @MartinSmith, actually that's incorrect. You can manipulate temporary tables in a function but not other tables. Plus, you could always swap out temporary tables for table variables.

Comment: @James - No you can't manipulate `#temp` tables, try it. You will get error `2772: Cannot access temporary tables from within a function.` Good point that you could just swap for `@table_vars` though.

Comment: @user680865 I'm not quite sure what you're after with the question "Can we use If Object_ID (View) and drop View?". You can't put the code that you have into a view; however, you can treat a table-valued function very similarly to the way you'd work with a view, i.e. SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTableValuedFunction(). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx for more information about table-valued functions.

Comment: @MartinSmith Doh! You're right. I don't remember what environment I was working in that allowed temp tables, but MS SQL doesn't. Table variables it is.

Answer (score 0):

--just took your code (it's quite messy), the  dbo.fn_GetBusinessDays function must be deterministic in order to work in a view

```
     create view test as        

SELECT 
   PtData.Pat_No                Progress_Pat_ID
    ,C_S = case when  dbo.fn_GetBusinessDays(firstship.Date_of_First_Shipment,LastShip.Date_of_Last_Shipment) > 80 then 'Yes'  
                                         when  dbo.fn_GetBusinessDays(firstship.Date_of_First_Shipment,LastShip.Date_of_Last_Shipment) <= 80 then 'No' 
                                        else ''
                                        end
    ,P_Last_Name = PtData.P_LName
    ,PtData.DReg        Reg
    FROM dbo.tbld_PatSum PtData
    inner join vd_PSum ps
        on PtData.P = ps.P_ID
    inner join S_M.dbo.Pat__c ps1 
        on PtData.Pt_ID = ps1.Id              
        left join (
            select 
            Pt_id = Pat_Id,
            Date_of_First_Shipment = min(DeliveryDate)
            from vd_View  po
            group by Pat_Id  ) firstship    
        on PtData.Pt_ID = firstship.Pt_Id     
        left join (select 
    Pt_id = Pat_Id,
    Date_of_Last_Shipment = max(DeliveryDate) 
from vd_View  po
group by Pat_Id  ) LastShip      
        on PtData.Pt_ID = LastShip.Pt_Id      
        WHERE PtData.Pat_No IS NOT NULL 
        AND PtData.ActiveStatus<>'Gen Info'
```